# Pytest add arguments to playwright browser

Tags: automated-tests, pytest, playwright

How to send a browser argument to a browser from playwright under pytest?
For example: I need to call firefox --profile=/directoryofmyprofile

Comment: How are you launching the browser? You can [add the flag there](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-option-args).